# Select random char from string in Common Lisp

Tags: string, list, common-lisp

Im learning Common Lisp and writing a simple password generator as an intro project.

Here is my code:

```
(setq chars
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789")
(print (nth (random (length chars)) chars))
```

But using CLISP I just get

```
*** - NTH: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789" is not a list
```

I thought every string in Lisp was a list? How can I "cast" the string to a list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[NTH](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_nth.htm#nth) works only for lists. Strings are not lists, but vectors of characters.

Here is the [dictionary for strings](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_string.htm). `CHAR` is an accessor for strings.

```
CL-USER 7 > (char "abc" 1)
#\b
```

Since strings are also sequences, all sequence operations apply. See: [Sequence dictionary](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/c_sequen.htm).

```
CL-USER 8 > (elt "abc" 1)
#\b
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. For my case I also found that CLISP doesn't seed its RNG so I had to say `(setf *random-state* (make-random-state t))` or I'd get the same result every time. cf http://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/mailman/message/12276431/

Answer (score 3):

Lisp is an interactive system. Learn to have conversations with the REPL:

`CL-USER> (type-of "abc")
(SIMPLE-ARRAY CHARACTER (3))`

You should get a similar result from CLISP.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I get `(SIMPLE-BASE-STRING 3)` from CLISP. Thanks for the `type-of` I will add it to my toolbox :)

Comment: Then I have another function for you: `subtypep`. Try `(subtypep (type-of "abc") 'array)` and `(subtypep (type-of "abc") 'list)`.

Answer (score 0):

A string is not a list. Not everything is a list in Lisp ;)

You can use `coerce` to create a list of the characters `(coerce "some string" 'list)`.

Comment: It's true that that can be done, but that creates an intermediate list, which is completely unnecessary in this case.  There are functions for accessing characters in strings (and element of vectors and arrays, more generally).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: You're right; just putting the possibility for conversion out there.